# Why countblank function can't get value for specified range?

Tags: excel, function, count

The countblank function to count all the blanks in a certain column.

[image]

Now you can see what happened! I input `=countblank(a2:a6)` in cell `a7`,and click enter.

[image]

No error info pop up,no value get.
I have upload the `sample.xls` file in dropbox,you can download it and have a try.
[sample.xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ei8sb59epi44t97/sample.xls?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample A7 cell format is 'Text'. Change it to 'General' and reenter formula.

Comment: your not `youe`.